# Send UDP commands using Batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, udp, netcat

This is sort of a basic question, there's just one piece of the puzzle that I'm missing somewhere.  I'm trying to write a batch script to change my smart home light bulbs to a specific color using netcat and UDP commands.  If I open command prompt, type this:

`ncat -u 192.168.1.3 38899`

A connection is established successfully to my smart light bulb, and then I can type this:

`{"id":1,"method":"setPilot","params":{"r":0,"g":0,"b":255,"dimming":100}}`

Which sends the UDP message to the bulb, and successfully changes it to blue.
The problem is I can't seem to get this process down to one line of code for use in a batch script, for example if I send this in a command line window:

```
ncat -u 192.168.1.3 38899 {"id":1,"method":"setPilot","params":{"r":0,"g":0,"b":255,"dimming":100}}
```

I get an error that I'm trying to specify more than one port.  If called from a batch script, the connection will establish, then pause, and I can then send the UDP command by typing it into the open cmd window, but that defeats the purpose.  I'm sure this is a simple solution that I'm just not aware of, would someone be able to help me out?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution! If I type

```
echo {"id":1,"method":"setPilot","params":{"r":0,"g":0,"b":255,"dimming":100}} | ncat -u -w 1 192.168.1.95 38899
```

It works!  Basically, echoing my command, without quotes, then a pipe | then my ncat connection.  Hope this helps anyone else trying to do the same thing.